# Using a function within a MySQL statement instead of sub-selects

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, subquery

I have the function:

```
function get_kwp($siteid){

$this->db->select('siteid')
         ->from('nwsite')
         ->where('siteid', $siteid);
}
```

I now want to include this function within another MySQL statement to save having to do a sub-select every time i need to call it.

This is the other MySQL statement that i need it to be called into:

```
$this->db->select("day, month, get_kwp($siteid) AS kwp")
         ->from('nwsite');
```

this doesn't seem to execute the function get_kwp().

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think you usin CodeIgniter so you should use some `join` or `union` in your query, also you can execute your query (if it's CodeIgniter) like `$this->db->query("select a,b,c from table where condition")` just without any methods nesting

Comment: Yes i am using codeigniter but i wanted the subquery to be done in a function so i don't have to write it out for the other 13 queries where it is going to be used.

Comment: @Impearce1 well, Active Records automatically escapes any values, so you've no choices but revert to manual queries or the nice solution by Jan-Henk

Answer (score 2):

A simple Google on CodeIgniter subqueries returned the following result: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Subqueries

You cannot include a PHP function call in a SQL SELECT statement. You should build the subquery in your database statement. Use the link I gave to see how to actually do it.

**EDIT**

I just saw that the article references a library on GitHub, but the installation of this library is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION get_kwp(Mysite_id INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
  DECLARE result INTEGER;
  SELECT siteid INTO result FROM nwsite WHERE siteid = Mysite_id LIMIT 1;
  RETURN result;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And use that in your query:

```
SELECT day, month, get_kwp('$siteid') AS kwp FROM nwsite;
```